# Javascript not working in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hey guys i have a really easy small question.  For some reason this code isn't working and i've been changing/looking at it for hours now.  I'm getting close but still it says 'Error: File Not Found'.  Heres my snippet:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
<!--
   

  document.write("[insert_php] if(!file_exists('../ftp/BCSMMR_Daily.csv')) { [/insert_php]");
    document.write("[insert_php] die('Error: File not found'); [/insert_php]");
    document.write("[insert_php] } else { [/insert_php]");
    document.write("[insert_php] echo 'something worked'; [/insert_php]");
    document.write("[insert_php] } [/insert_php]");
  
//--></script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert a WordPress shortcode via JavaScript? If so, it's definitely not going to work...Why not use plain PHP or JS for this?

Comment: Hey @Mevius thank you so much for the quick response. I tried using just plain old php and i read that i needed a plugin because php wasn't read normally hence the [insert_php] tags

Comment: Can you read the file in plain php code without '[insert_php]'?

Comment: Hey @Sky , when i replace the [insert_php] tags with regular php tags (like i had before) the page is blank which led me to believe that regular tags wouldn't work.  My apologies if i sound stupid but just trying to sort what looks like a bigger mess, out.

Comment: As your error message says, it's the file can't be found, so I think you should check if you can get the file with regular `php` code first.

Comment: Thanks @Sky i'm looking into this more.  Turns out no matter where i put the file, it comes back saying the file isn't found but like i said it is there...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all your help looking in different areas.  Turns out it was a stupid parenthesis error that was throwing everything off.  It's working now and onto other importa